# Is Conformal selfmap same as automorphism?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is Conformal selfmap same as automorphism?
I think they are because automorphism is isomorphism from U to U and Isomorphism is bijective map. 
Conformal selfmap is Analytic bijective map from U to U so if Isomorphism is Analytic then I think Conformal selfmap is same as automorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider a complex domain, yes they are. Indeed (**edited**)

1. $f\in C^\infty$ with $f'\neq0$
2. $f$ analytic with $f'\neq0$
3. $f$ conformal

are all equivalent. $f'\neq 0$ implies that $f^{-1}$ too is conformal.

If the domains are real then an isomorphism need not be conformal: for instance, reflections through an axis are isomorphism of $\mathbb R^n$ which do not preserve the orientation. But now I notice that your question is tagged 'complex-analysis'...

Comment: Andreas: But conformal map is analytic bijection. How you take $f' \neq 0$, but do not state that $f$ is bijection? Or is it same to state that $f$ has $f^{-1}$ which is conformal and $f$ is bijection? I didn't find info from the web about the claim I asked. Can you give any site from web about this claim?

Comment: @alvoutila We already know that $f$ is a bijection because it is a **selfmap**. Then the fact that it is conformal ensures that $f'\neq0$ so that you know that $f^{-1}$ too is conformal with $\frac{d}{dz}f^{-1}=\frac{1}{f'\circ f^{-1}}$. If you already know that *a conformal map is bijective if and only if it is biolomorphic*, then I don't get what you are asking.

Comment: Andreas: But $f$ can be selfmap, but still be injective in domain and range being same? I mean is it bijection regardless of the function?

Comment: @alvoutila It seems we might have a different concept of *selfmap*: I am not an English native speaker but I have always thought of a **selfmap** as a **bijective** map from a set to itself by definition (and your question states that `Conformal selfmap is Analytic bijective map from U to U` so that it seems you just need the fact that the inverse is conformal too, don't you?). On the other hand, if selfmaps need not be bijective, then the answer is **NO**: think of $f(z)=z/2$ from the disk of radius $1$ to itself. It is analytic but clearly not an isomorphism.

Comment: @AndreasT.. Yes, but why you must show that $f^{-1}$ is conformal to show that conformal selfmap is automorphism?

Comment: @laovultai I see your point: if a homomorphism is invertible, then the inverse is a homomorphism too. There was no need to point out that $f^{-1}$ is conformal as well. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: well. If $f$ is bijective, then it is invertible and so I understand now. One more question; does $f \in C^{\infty}$ mean that $f$ is infinitelyt differentiable? And if yes, where you state in your answer that $f$ is bijective?

Comment: Yes, it does. And about the bijective part, it has already been discussed in [one comment above](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296312/is-conformal-selfmap-same-as-automorphism/296314?noredirect=1#comment646203_296314).